# Druid sql functions analogue to Prometheus 'rate' and 'histogram_quantile'

Tags: prometheus, druid

I wrote an application and deployed a Prometheus, that scrapes metrics from the app and stores it in Druid (I'm forced to use this database in production for metrics). Now I want to make a dashboard in Grafana to monitor the application. If the datasource is Prometheus, one query would look like

```
sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{le="0.3"}[5m])) by (job)
```

another

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m])) by (le))
```

I wonder how to build the same queries with the use of Druid SQL on the Druid datasource?

I haven't found any analog to the `rate` or `histogram_quantile` functions in Druid documentation. I'm aware of data sketches https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-quantiles.html, but I don't see how to apply them here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the prometheus functions; they look like they might be window functions - if so, that's not currently available in druid directly.